# Fixed fans by update GPU drivers, broke everything else by installing and/or removing bumblebee

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kde, upstart, bumblebee

New Linux user here, and I'm already breaking everything.

So I installed KDE neon. First problem I had was my fans running at full speed constantly. I don't remember what I did exactly, I believe I just updated my nvidia drivers and they stopped. Next problem I had was my battery, it was draining insanely fast. I looked up the issues, and the most common fix I came across was installing bumblebee. So I tried it.

As soon as I did, my fans started running again. So I tried to remove bumblebee using remove and using purge. Everything looked fine, I walked away and came back to a screen that said "The screen locker is broken and unlocking is not possible anymore. In order to unlock switch to a virtual terminal (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F2), log in and execute the command:"

I tried to get to the terminal but it wouldn't let me. So I rebooted, and after the KDE neon boot screen, it just went black. I can ctrl + alt + f1,2 etc. But that is it. If I ctrl alt f7 when in the terminal, whatever was on the terminal just freezes onto my screen until I jump back into it.

I asked on reddit and was told to post the results of sudo ubuntu-drivers, so here they are:

```
nvidia-370
nvidia-364
nvidia-361
intel-microcode
nvidia-367
nvidia-358
```

I've tried sudo stop KDE, and sudo restart KDE but each time it says unable to connect to upstart: failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: connection refused

So instead of searching for solutions and finding multiple ones and breaking stuff more, I decided to come here. This is all on an Asus ROG 501vw with a skylake cpu and a 960m dedicated gpu.